# limiting a correlated subquery to just one record

Tags: correlated-subquery

I am trying to use a correlated subquery, but I am trying to limit it to the "best" record.  When I use SQL very similiar to what follows, I get two rows per BigTable.identifier, and I wish to have only one.  In the 'UNION' statement, the second half is more desirable than the first half.  However, sometimes the first half will be needed.  Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
select 
  BigTable.identifier,
  Correlated.ID,
  Correlated.Effective_Date,
  Correlated.Period_Number

from
  BigTable

inner join

( 
select
  TOP 2147483647
  Table3.identifier,
  Table4.Effective_Date,
  Table4.Period_Number

from
  Table3
inner join Table4 on Table3.matching_key = Table4.matching_key
where
  Table4.Period_Number = 0
order by Table4.Effective_Date desc

UNION

 select 
  TOP 2147483647
  Table3.Identifer,
  Table4.Effective_Date,
  Table4.Period_Number
 from
   Table3
 inner join Table5 on Table3.matching-key = Table5.matching-key
 inner join Table4 on Table5.key1 = Table4.key1 and
    Table5.key2 = Table4.key2
where
   Table4.period_number = 1 
order by Table4.Effective_Date desc
) as Correlated 

on BigTable.identifier = Correlated.identifier
```

Comment: You don't say how you decide which is better. Perhaps the inner queries themselves can filter out records where EXISTS a record which would be eligible for the other part of the UNION. Perhaps theres some type of ranking or score that can be assigned to each row of the UNION to let the higher one "win". Depends on the details of how you will determine which one stays.

Comment: I'd like to select as "best" by taking the top-most record from the union statement and ranking based on period_number desc (i.e., prefers 1 in the bottom half over 0 in the top half), and the latest effective date.  However, I can't figure out where to put the "top 1" statement and still get all the records from the BigTable.

Answer (score 0):

If each sub-query in that UNION had some condition which EXCLUDED the row if it was less-preferred, you would never see the less-preferred rows in the UNION. 
So, if each were to have a NOT EXISTS (.... a better row in the other side of the union ....), you would eliminate less-preferred rows at the root.

I'm not clear on how you want to use effective date. Assuming you mean that you prefer Period=1 but if the Effective date is less you prefer Period=0, then something like this might work.

```
select 
  BigTable.identifier,
  Correlated.ID,
  Correlated.Effective_Date,
  Correlated.Period_Number

from
  BigTable

inner join

( 
select
  TOP 2147483647
  Table3.identifier,
  Table4.Effective_Date,
  Table4.Period_Number

from
  Table3
inner join Table4 on Table3.matching_key = Table4.matching_key
where
  Table4.Period_Number = 0
 AND NOT EXISTS 
   (select 1 
    from Table5 T5 inner join Table4 T4
    on T5.key1 = T4.key1 and T5.key2 = T4.key2 
    where Table3.matching-key = T5.matching-key
      and (T4.Effective_Date >= Table4.Effective_Date  and T4.Period_Number = 1)
   )
order by Table4.Effective_Date desc

UNION

 select 
  TOP 2147483647
  Table3.Identifer,
  Table4.Effective_Date,
  Table4.Period_Number
 from
   Table3
 inner join Table5 on Table3.matching-key = Table5.matching-key
 inner join Table4 on Table5.key1 = Table4.key1 and
    Table5.key2 = Table4.key2
where
   Table4.period_number = 1 
 AND NOT EXISTS 
   (select 1 
    from Table4 T4
    where Table3.matching-key = T4.matching-key
      and (T4.Period_Number > 0)
      and (T4.Effective_Date > Table4.Effective_Date  and T4.Period_Number = 0)
   )
order by Table4.Effective_Date desc
) as Correlated 

on BigTable.identifier = Correlated.identifier
```

Comment: Darius X, thanks! The "not exists" clause is just what I need.  :)